# How to make vertex shapes different in R plot.igraph?

Tags: r, plot, social-networking, igraph

I'm using R and the package **igraph** to plot a network. The many vertices in the graph belong to 50 groups. For each group, I would like to use a unique color/vertex shape combination to distinguish it from the others.

Is there a way to plot some vertices as say circles and others as squares according to their attributes?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/496488) for us to work with.

Comment: See `?igraph.plotting` - it has examples at the bottom showing how to alter characteristics when plotted.